# Cannot Open database "

Tags: ms-access

From time to time I get the above message but when I click okay everything works fine.  It happens when I do a save as or just opening a form - which it doesn't always do it just sometimes.  I did a search and some people get this message when their database is too big which is not the case here since it is only 17 MB.  I can work around it because all I have to do is click okay and everything is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would look at Compact&Repair and other [Corruption recovery steps](http://allenbrowne.com/recover.html).

Comment: do you have any linked tables?  If so, are any of those links invalid?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this normally means I've reached or exceeded the 2G database size limit.  Delete any unnecessary tables and then compact & repair.

If you reload large tables from another source frequently, delete the table first (or it's contents, anyway), then compact & repair, then reload the source data.  Each re-load seems to eat up more space, and the deletes don't release the space.

If this doesn't free up enough space, you may need to link large tables from another source instead of load them locally.